# Recommendations for Open Source Ruby Encyrption Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need a gem to perform simple string encryption and decryption in Ruby for values I want to store in the database.  Can anyone suggest a good open source gem to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean with simple - the encryption algorithm or the use of the gem?

If you need nontoy encryption, then I would suggest you take a look at the 'crypt' gem.